# How To Show Multiple Alert Dialogs In Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have one `AlertDialog` that shows three buttons: **CANCEL**, **SHOW CONFIRMATION**, **OK**.

When the **SHOW CONFIRMATION** is selected, I want another `AlertDialog` to appear, BUT maintaining the first `AlertDialog`.

How can this be done???

I tried to not call `dialog.dismiss`, but still , when the second one appears, the first one will be dismissed automatically.

Please help. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `onShowListener` of `AlertDialogue`, like the following

```
alert.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                Button button = alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                    // Your implementation code for show next Dialogue
                    }
                });
            }
});
```

**Do nothing in `onClick` of Alert Dialogue's positive button**

Comment: Thank you very much. I learned something very useful today! :)